# Como adicionar um link no menu do Redmine apenas para os usuários logados?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

Criei um link, na parte superior do Redmine, para um determinado setor da empresa. Preciso saber como ocultar este link, caso não haja nenhum usuário logado.

O botão foi criado no arquivo init.rb do meu plugin contendo a seguinte sinatxe...

```
menu :top_menu, :my_link, { :controller => 'my_controller', :action => 'index' },
     :last => true,  :caption => :my_caption
```

Ja tentei usar `User.current.logged?` mas não tive sucesso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faz assim:

```
menu :top_menu, :my_link, {:controller => 'my_controller', :action => 'index'},
     :caption => :my_caption, :if => Proc.new { User.current.logged? }
```

Referência: https://github.com/Tide/menu_link/blob/master/init.rb

Comment: Agora está funcional!

Comment: Legal, resolveu? Se sim, marque a resposta como certa :)